# Prevent QtWebEngine from redirecting to specific domains

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtwebengine

I'm working with QtWebEngine 5 (python) mainly for crawling purposes (but not just). 
I would like to control the qt redirection in the following way:

**before** each url loads, i would like to have the ability to decide whether it should continue with the redirection or not.

AFAIU, the Interceptor class is not the right one because it is after the url has been loaded, but perhaps i am mistaken.

I would like to present an example for what i would like to achieve:
let's stay i start from the link a.com, the redirect to b.com and it redirects to c.com. 
Before each url loads qt will call a function that will decide whether to continue or not like (pseudo code)

```
def should_continue(url):
   if url.contains(x.com):
        log("got to x, not sending request")
        return False
   else:
        return True
```

Comment: The documentation states that QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor is for "... blocking, and modifying URL requests before they reach the networking stack of Chromium." So your assumption that it's called after the URL has loaded seems incorrect.

Comment: @MrEricSir thanks. Maybe I misunderstood that, however, is it possible to order it not to load the page and stop the redirecton?